# Qt QTimeSpan Error LNK2019

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Windows 7, QCreator, Qt 5.0 and my PC is x64.

I get the following errors while using [QTimeSpan](http://www.eraserboxtips.blogspot.com/2013/06/qtimespan-guide_21.html):

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QTimeSpan::~QTimeSpan(void)" (__imp_??1QTimeSpan@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class QTimeSpan __cdecl operator*(class QTimeSpan const &,int)" (__imp_??D@YA?AVQTimeSpan@@AEBV0@H@Z) referenced in function "class QTimeSpan __cdecl operator*(int,class QTimeSpan const &)" (??D@YA?AVQTimeSpan@@HAEBV0@@Z)

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class QTimeSpan __cdecl operator-(class QTime const &,class QTime const &)" (__imp_??G@YA?AVQTimeSpan@@AEBVQTime@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)


mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class QTime __cdecl operator+(class QTime const &,class QTimeSpan const &)" (__imp_??H@YA?AVQTime@@AEBV0@AEBVQTimeSpan@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)

debug\Midpoint3_1.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I have tried adding the Qt/libs directory to paths in my computer's 'Environment Variables' but failed.

Here's the source code:
//Midpoint3_1.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-07-01T03:58:17
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT += widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Midpoint3_1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp\


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/msvc2012_64/include/QTimeSpan/qtimespan.h

FORMS    += \
    mainwindow.ui
```

//mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include "QTimeSpan/qtimespan.h"
#include <QTime>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int))
           ,ui->percentage,SLOT(setValue(int)));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QTime vtime1 = ui->time1->time();
    QTime vtime2 = ui->time2->time();
    QTimeSpan vspan = vtime2 - vtime1;
    int vpercentage = ui->percentage->value();
    QTime vtime3 = vtime1 + (vpercentage/100) * vspan;
    //ui->time3->setText(QString );
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

//main.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

There's also a mainwindow.ui, here's the source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>284</width>
    <height>259</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Time Midpoint Calculator</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>241</width>
      <height>191</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Time 1</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QTimeEdit" name="time1"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Time 2</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QTimeEdit" name="time2">
           <property name="time">
            <time>
             <hour>12</hour>
             <minute>0</minute>
             <second>0</second>
            </time>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QSlider" name="horizontalSlider">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>128</width>
           <height>19</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>20000</width>
           <height>19</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximum">
          <number>100</number>
         </property>
         <property name="singleStep">
          <number>1</number>
         </property>
         <property name="value">
          <number>50</number>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Percentage</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QSpinBox" name="percentage">
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>60</width>
             <height>22</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="value">
            <number>50</number>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Calculate</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Output Time</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="time3">
         <property name="text">
          <string>6:00:00 AM</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>284</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Help</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionThe_Algorithm"/>
    <addaction name="actionThe_Algorithm_2"/>
    <addaction name="actionAbout_Midpoint"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionThe_Algorithm">
   <property name="text">
    <string>What is 'Fraction'?</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionThe_Algorithm_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>The Algorithm</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAbout_Midpoint">
   <property name="text">
    <string>About Midpoint</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

See [here](http://www.eraserboxtips.blogspot.com/2013/06/qtimespan-guide_21.html) for the source code for qtimespan.h.

And here's how the program looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to include and link to "C" libraries in your C++ application. If your QT is a C library, then calling convention would be __cdecl, but C++ may be looking for linking with __stdcall or someother convention.
In such a scenario if you are sure you are using a C library to link with your CPP app, then include your C headers with

#ifdef _cplusplus

extern "C" {

#endif

#include < your hearder here >  //for example QtGui and QTCore etc headers here

#ifdef _cplusplus

}

#endif

This will ensure you will be able to C library without any issues from CPP application

Comment: QTimeSpan is C++; in which file should I add the C headers?

Comment: My personal guess is that some aspect of QTimeSpan isn't included in my project properly. My QTimeSpan download came with a .cpp, .h and .pri. I only put the .h in my project

Comment: Possible that you may have to add the .cpp in your project as well.
I've had issues like that in the past.
Including the .h gives the declarations, then the linker freaks out because it cannot find the definitions. Try adding the .cpp as well.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx
According to them a LNK2019 error can be caused by missing function body. So adding the .cpp may solve the problem.

Comment: You have to either link with the QTSpan library, or you have to include the .cpp file as suggested in above comments, one of them should definately work.

Comment: `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QTime vtime1 = ui->time1->time();
    QTime vtime2 = ui->time2->time();
    // QTimeSpan vspan = vtime2 - vtime1;
    int vpercentage = ui->percentage->value();
    //QTime vtime3;
    //QTime vtime3 = vtime1 + (vpercentage/100) * vspan;
    //ui->time3->setText(QString );
}
` runs fine when I do this "unit testing"

Comment: Run "dumpbin /exports" on the dll/app to know what is the mangled name for the erroring function name, and match to see if the exported function calling convention matches that of the method call you are making.

Comment: nvm I'll just figure it out

Comment: Just in case anyone is actively trying to figure this out, I think that my mistake is "A QTimeSpan can be created by initializing it directly with a length and optionally with a reference (start) date, or by subtracting two QDate or QDateTime values." whereas I have ussed Qtime instead of Qdate or QdateTime in order to calculate the value of QtimeSpan, I must change the values of Qtime inputted from the form into values of QdateTime, and then find QtimeSpan using that, and then add QtimeSpan to Qtime vtime1 and finally find vtime3.

Comment: In the end I just gave up fixing it. I just abandoned the whole idea of using QTimeSpan, instead I just used QTime etc. to get what I wanted.

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested, I found that if you have problems like LNK 2019, many times you can fix it by just doing clean,run qmake,rebuild,run. I even made a video showing how to do it. However, I don't know whether it would solve the problem stated in my question.